# Get value of class members with out AttributeError

Tags: python, attributeerror

See my example

```
class MyClass1:
    name = 'A'
class MyClass2:
    foo = MyClass1()

obj1 = MyClass2()
```

Below code will result `AttributeError` if `obj1` or `foo` is `False`.

```
print obj1.foo.name
```

So I  write following

```
if obj1:
    if obj1.foo:
        if obj1.foo.name:
            print obj1.foo.name
```

What is the best way? Can I avoid the repeating words in my code ?

Comment: why would you set them to `False`? Nothing in the code indicates how that could happen and why.

Comment: Some time it may be False >>> obj1.foo = False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `try/except` syntax to catch the exception.

```py
try:
    print obj1.foo.name
except AttributeError:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be simplified to two lines:

```
if obj1 and obj1.foo and obj1.foo.name:
    print obj1.foo.name
```

It checks conditions one-by-one, and if any condition of all joined by `and` is falsy the whole `... and ... and ...` condition becomes falsy and doesn't check inner conditions further.

Answer (score -2):

The pythonic way to resolve this is by using `try/execept`

```
try:
   name = obj1.foo.name
except AttributeError:
    # raise error or pass
```